# ROBOT command fails to run failed test cases

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Robot command fails to pick (and execute) failed test cases in output.xml.
If someone can help to fix this issue, it would be great.

Below is command with error :

```
/home/xxx/Documents/xxxx/AutoCode/VirEnv/bin/robot --rerunfailed output.xml -L TRACE --variable ENV:c4-test --variable RUN_ON_LOCALHOST:true --variable CONF: --variable BROWSER:chrome /home/xxx/Documents/xxxx/AutoCode/Automation/tests/*

[ ERROR ] Suite 'Debug & MasterData & Navigation & Security & SetUp & UserInterface' contains no tests matching name 'Debug.SecurityAdminPermissions.Verify Fail'.

Try --help for usage information.

Process finished with exit code 252
```

================== OS and Package versions used ======================

OS :

```
Ubuntu 20.04.10.11
```

Package                         Version

---

async-generator                 1.10
attrs                           22.2.0
bcrypt                          4.0.1
beautifulsoup4                  4.11.2
certifi                         2022.12.7
cffi                            1.15.1
charset-normalizer              3.1.0
configparser                    5.3.0
crqacore                        1.5.1
crqarobot                       1.3.9
cryptography                    39.0.2
curlify                         2.2.1
decorator                       5.1.1
Dialogs                         1.0
et-xmlfile                      1.1.0
exceptiongroup                  1.1.0
h11                             0.14.0
idna                            3.4
importlib-resources             5.12.0
jsondiff                        2.0.0
jsonpath-ng                     1.5.3
jsonschema                      4.17.3
namedlist                       1.8
natsort                         8.3.1
openpyxl                        3.1.2
outcome                         1.2.0
paramiko                        3.0.0
pdfminer                        20191125
pip                             22.3.1
pkgutil_resolve_name            1.3.10
ply                             3.11
pycparser                       2.21
pycryptodome                    3.17
PyMySQL                         1.0.2
PyNaCl                          1.5.0
pyOpenSSL                       23.0.0
PyPDF2                          3.0.1
pyrsistent                      0.19.3
PySocks                         1.7.1
python-dateutil                 2.8.2
pytz                            2022.7.1
requests                        2.28.2
retrying                        1.3.4
robotframework                  6.0.2
robotframework-databaselibrary  1.2.4
robotframework-jsonlibrary      0.5
robotframework-pabot            2.14.0
robotframework-pythonlibcore    4.1.2
robotframework-requests         0.9.4
robotframework-selenium2library 3.0.0
robotframework-seleniumlibrary  6.0.0
robotframework-stacktrace       0.4.1
robotremoteserver               1.1.1
selenium                        4.8.2
setuptools                      65.5.1
six                             1.16.0
sniffio                         1.3.0
sortedcontainers                2.4.0
soupsieve                       2.4
sshtunnel                       0.4.0
trio                            0.22.0
trio-websocket                  0.9.2
typing_extensions               4.5.0
urllib3                         1.26.14
wheel                           0.38.4
wsproto                         1.2.0
xlrd                            2.0.1
xmldict                         0.4.1
zipp                            3.15.0

same command without "--rerunfailed output.xml" works fine.

Comment: Try adding `--runemptysuite`

Comment: It does not pick failed test cases.

Comment: Can anyone please help?